# Conversion C dll header to Delphi pascal header

Tags: c, delphi, dll, header, pascal

please can you help me? I need convert this C header to pascal header

```
#include <wtypes.h>
extern "C"
{

typedef struct _sms_report
{
    char            sUserNumber[24];           
    unsigned char   cPort;                      
    unsigned char   cErrorCode;             
    unsigned char   cCount;                 
    unsigned char   cSuccCount;             

    _sms_report()
    {
        memset(this,0,sizeof(_sms_report));
    }
}_SMS_REPORT;





enum ERRORCODE
{
    _SUCCESS = 0,  
    _INVALID = 1,  
    _PORTCANTUSED = 2, 
    _TIMEOUT = 3,  
      _SOMEFAIL = 4, 
    _UNKNOW = 255   
};



typedef void (*On_WIAConnect)(short conn_no);          
typedef void (*On_WIADisConnect)(short conn_no);          
typedef void (*On_SendSmsReport)(short conn_no,char* seq,unsigned short numberCount,_SMS_REPORT* smsReport);
typedef void (*On_ReceiveSmsMsg)(short conn_no,unsigned char portno,char* seq,char* CallerNumber,char* text,
                                unsigned char type,char* receivetime,char timezone);
typedef void (*On_WIAStatusMsg)(short conn_no,char* seq,unsigned char portnum,unsigned char *pPortStatus);
typedef void (*On_SendUSSDResponse)(short conn_no,unsigned char portno,char* seq,unsigned char errcode);
typedef void (*On_ReceiveUSSDMsg)(short conn_no,unsigned char portno,char* seq,char* text,unsigned char status);


struct CBHandler
{
    On_WIAConnect _OnWIAConnect; 
    On_WIADisConnect  _OnWIADisConnect;
    On_SendSmsReport _OnSendSmsReport; 
    On_ReceiveSmsMsg _OnReceiveSmsMsg; 
    On_WIAStatusMsg  _OnWIAStatusMsg; 
    On_SendUSSDResponse _OnSendUSSDResponse;
    On_ReceiveUSSDMsg _OnReceiveUSSDMsg;
};


bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall InitLib(CBHandler *);
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall StartRun(char *svrip,WORD port);
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetSvrInfo(char *svrip,WORD port);
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SendSms(short conn_no,unsigned char PortNo,char* dstNumber,
                unsigned char msgCodingType,char* text,unsigned char type,char * seq);
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SendUSSD(short conn_no,unsigned char PortNo,unsigned char status,
                                    char* text,char * seq);
bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall UninitLib();
};
```

I make thius pascal header:

```
unit zfsmsdll;

interface
uses
{$IFDEF WIN32}
  Windows;
{$ELSE}
  Wintypes, WinProcs;
{$ENDIF}

const
 DLL_NAME = 'zfsmsdll.dll';

type
 TSmsReport = record

   sUserNumber: packed array [1..24] of Char;
         cPort: Byte;
    cErrorCode: Byte;
        cCount: Byte;
      cSuccCount: Byte;

 end;

 TErrorCode = (

      ecSuccess = 0,
      ecInvalid = 1,
  ecPortCansued = 2,
      ecTimeout = 3,
     ecSomeFail = 4,
      ecUnknown = 255
 );


 TOnWIAConnect = procedure ( conn_no: SmallInt) of object; cdecl;
 TOnWIADisconnect = procedure ( conn_no: SmallInt) of object; cdecl;
 TOnSendSmsReport = procedure (conn_no: SmallInt;  seq: PChar; numberCount: Word; smsReport: TSmsReport) of object; cdecl;
 TOnReceiveSmsMsg = procedure (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; CallerNumber: PChar; text: PChar;
                               ttype: Byte; receivetime: PChar; timezone: Char) of object; cdecl;
 TOnWIAStatusMsg = procedure (conn_no: SmallInt; seq: PChar; portnum: Byte; pPortStatus: Byte) of object; cdecl;
 TOnSendUSSDResponse = procedure (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; errcode: Byte) of object; cdecl;
 TOnReceiveUSSDMsg = procedure (conn_no: SmallInt; portno:Byte; seq: PChar; text: PChar; status: Byte ) of object; cdecl;


 PCBhandler = ^TCBHandler;
 TCBHandler = record
       HOnWIAConnect: TOnWIAConnect;
    HOnWIADisconnect: TOnWIADisconnect;
    HOnSendSmsReport: TOnSendSmsReport;
    HOnReceiveSmsMsg: TOnReceiveSmsMsg;
     HOnWIAStatusMsg: TOnWIAStatusMsg;
 HOnSendUSSDResponse: TOnSendUSSDResponse;
   HOnReceiveUSSDMsg: TOnReceiveUSSDMsg;
 end;

function InitLib ( Handler: PCBhandler ):Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;
function StartRun ( SrvIp: PChar; Port: Word ):Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;
function GetSvrInfo ( SrvIp: PChar; Port: Word ):Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;
function SendSms (conn_no: SmallInt; PortNo: Byte; dstNumber: PChar; msgCodingType: Byte;
                  text: PChar; ttype: Byte; seq: PChar):Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;
function SendUSSD (conn_no: SmallInt; PortNo: Byte; status: Byte; text: PChar;
                   seq: PChar):Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;
function UninitLib ():Boolean; cdecl; external DLL_NAME;


implementation

end.
```

When i call InitLib function where parameter is record of methods pointers that initialization done but adter method InitLib program throw excepotion access violation type. I think that probem is in declaring method pointers. This is my main form unit:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,zfsmsdll;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    mmoLog: TMemo;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  THandlerEvents = class

    procedure OnWIAConnect ( conn_no: SmallInt);cdecl;

    procedure OnWIADisconnect ( conn_no: SmallInt);cdecl;
    procedure OnSendSmsReport (conn_no: SmallInt;  seq: PChar; numberCount: Word; smsReport: TSmsReport);cdecl;
    procedure OnReceiveSmsMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; CallerNumber: PChar; text: PChar;
                               ttype: Byte; receivetime: PChar; timezone: Char);cdecl;
    procedure OnWIAStatusMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; seq: PChar; portnum: Byte; pPortStatus: Byte);cdecl;
    procedure OnSendUSSDResponse (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; errcode: Byte);cdecl;
    procedure OnReceiveUSSDMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; portno:Byte; seq: PChar; text: PChar; status: Byte );cdecl;

  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  HandlerEvents: THandlerEvents;

  InitHandler: TCBhandler;



implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure THandlerEvents.OnWIAConnect ( conn_no: SmallInt);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnConnect processed');
end;

procedure THandlerEvents.OnWIADisconnect ( conn_no: SmallInt);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnWIADisconnect processed');
end;
procedure THandlerEvents.OnSendSmsReport (conn_no: SmallInt;  seq: PChar; numberCount: Word; smsReport: TSmsReport);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnSendSmsReport processed');
end;
procedure THandlerEvents.OnReceiveSmsMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; CallerNumber: PChar; text: PChar;
                               ttype: Byte; receivetime: PChar; timezone: Char);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnReceiveSmsMsg processed');
end;
procedure THandlerEvents.OnWIAStatusMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; seq: PChar; portnum: Byte; pPortStatus: Byte);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnWIAStatusMsg processed');
end;
procedure THandlerEvents.OnSendUSSDResponse (conn_no: SmallInt; portno: Byte; seq: PChar; errcode: Byte);cdecl;
begin
  Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnSendUSSDResponse processed');
end;
procedure THandlerEvents.OnReceiveUSSDMsg (conn_no: SmallInt; portno:Byte; seq: PChar; text: PChar; status: Byte );cdecl;
begin
 Form1.mmoLog.Lines.Add('OnReceiveUSSDMsg processed');
end;


procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

// try

     InitHandler.HOnWIAConnect := HandlerEvents.OnWIAConnect;
     InitHandler.HOnWIADisconnect := HandlerEvents.OnWIADisconnect;
     InitHandler.HOnSendSmsReport := HandlerEvents.OnSendSmsReport;
     InitHandler.HOnReceiveSmsMsg := HandlerEvents.OnReceiveSmsMsg;
     InitHandler.HOnWIAStatusMsg := HandlerEvents.OnWIAStatusMsg;
     InitHandler.HOnSendUSSDResponse := HandlerEvents.OnSendUSSDResponse;
     InitHandler.HOnReceiveUSSDMsg := HandlerEvents.OnReceiveUSSDMsg;

     if (InitLib(@InitHandler)) then
      begin
         mmoLog.Lines.Add('DLL initialized');
      end else
      begin
         mmoLog.Lines.Add('DLL NO initialized');
      end;

// except on e:Exception do
//  begin
//    mmoLog.Lines.Add('Exception:' + e.Message);
//  end;
// end;


end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 try
     if (UninitLib) then
      begin
         mmoLog.Lines.Add('DLL UNinitialized');
      end else
      begin
         mmoLog.Lines.Add('DLL NO UNinitialized');
      end;
 except on e:Exception do
  begin
    mmoLog.Lines.Add('Exception:' + e.Message);
  end;
 end;
end;

end.
```

Can you help ,me somebody? Thank you.

Comment: @StoryTeller Which details do you think should have been omitted here. I don't see which code from the question could be removed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it quite easily could have been demonstrated with a small struct and a single callback, for starters.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not really. You need to fix all the errors before the code will start working. Not just the `of object` error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, More importantly you also need to learn how to break your code apart to spot errors. Your'e a big man for taking the time to review the OPs entire code, but I doubt you needed to see all seven callbacks to tell them how to do it properly (Especially since they all shared the same basic flaw).

Comment: @StoryTeller I do know where you are coming from. However, I have some experience of such a question. After fixing the `of object` error, the code still fails because of the next error. So the question goes on and on and on! A so-called chameleon question!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yeah that is a good point. However, I still hope that in the future my comment will encourage the OP to start out with small attempts when treading into unknown territory for the first time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `of object` for all the callback functions. That is incorrect. The C header does not do that and so there is a binary mismatch. That explains your errors.

Fix the problem by removing all mention of `of object` from your Delphi unit.

Some other comments:

- C `char` maps to Delphi `AnsiChar`, or Delphi `Byte`. On a Unicode Delphi, your use of `Char` will be incorrect.
- Likewise you should use `PAnsiChar` rather than `PChar`.
- The functions `InitLIb`, `StartRun` etc. are declared as `__stdcall` in the C code. You've made them `cdecl` in your Delphi code.
- The fourth parameter of `On_SendSmsReport` takes a pointer to the struct. Your Delphi code is declared to receive the struct. You need to add that indirection and make the Delphi code also receive a pointer.
- The `pPortStatus` parameter of `On_WIAStatusMsg` is a pointer to a byte array. You've declared it in Delphi as `Byte`.

I suspect there are a handful more errors in your conversion. I recommend you go over it again very carefully.

Comment: Please, can you write me how convert "pointer to a byte array" from C to Delphi?

Comment: In the C code it is `unsigned char*`. Looking at the C code I think `unsigned char` is used for bytes and `char` is used for text. Since the function passes a pointer, I presume it is a pointer to an array. But I could be wrong. You'd have to read the documentation. All the same, your Delphi code needs to declare it to be `PByte`, that is a pointer to byte.

Comment: i am so sorry Mr. Heffernan , i am sitting on this problem over 10 hours and i need solution :-( I dont want to border you. How can i use corretly pascal header so it work? Compiller write me: [DCC Error] main.pas(86): E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer', and on site sulution is add 'of object' declaration, but its wrong in this case.

Comment: With a mis-match at an interface boundary, there are two possible resolutions. You can change either side of the interface to match the other. In this case you picked the wrong one. You can't change the C side of the interface so you have to make the Delphi side match. You cannot use `of object`. So remove it. Now you need to make your callbacks be plain old functions/procedures that are not methods of a class.

Comment: Finally i understand! It works!!! Thank you so much Mr.Heffernan. Much you have helped me! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm very please to hear that. Good luck!

Comment: Assuming record packing in Delphi and any foreign compiler is the same?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort All sane compilers on Windows follow the platform native rules for record alignment.

Comment: I looked it up, and $A+ is pretty close, since Delphi doesn't have SSE2 intrinsics. Delphi aligns in {$A+} size to maximally 8 bytes. If you have SSE2 registers as base types you would need {$A16+} since SSE2 would be a base field type that is 16-byte. I was not to deep into this because FPC defaults to other alignment directives. (though it supports the later introduced Delphi ones too). FPC does support SSE2 basetypes though. Maybe even AVX (Needing {$A32+} probably

Comment: oh, and I suddenly wonder what happens with "extended".

Comment: Extended has alignment of 16, I think!